# Get wrong date value after converting unix time stamp

Tags: swift, timestamp

I get a unix timestamp from server

```
1589275703283
```

when I tried to convert it from this website: https://www.epochconverter.com
I get the value of `Tuesday, 12 May 2020`

and I'm using this code to convert this timestamp to date that I can read

```
 func timeStringFromUnixTime(timestamp: Int64) -> String {
      let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp))
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd, MMMM yyyy"
      dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: NSTimeZone.default.identifier)
      let localDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
      return localDate
   }
```

but it passed me `22 February 52332`, which is obviously wrong

Could anyone help me where the problem come from?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timestamp `1589275703283` is way too big for a "normal" UNIX timestamp. It's in milliseconds instead of seconds (which `epochconverter.com` is smart enough to detect; it's printing *"Assuming that this timestamp is in milliseconds"*). So you need to divide your timestamp by 1000:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(timestamp) / 1000)
```